# $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation with $\ker T^{n-2}\neq \ker T^{n-1}$ has at most 2 eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space ($\dim V=n$) over field $\mathbb{F}$ algebraically closed field. Let $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation and $\ker T^{n-2}\neq\ker T^{n-1}$  so $T$ has 2 distinct eigenvalues at most.

My attempt: Because $\ker T^{n-2}\neq\ker T^{n-1}\Rightarrow \left\{ 0\right\} \subset\ker T\subset\ker T^{2}\subset\ker T^{3}\subset\dots$

This is because $\forall i \ker T^{i}\subseteq\ker T^{i+1}$ ($\forall v\in\ker T^{i+1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ker T^{i}\subseteq\ker T^{i+1}\Leftarrow T^{i+1}v=0\Leftarrow TT^{i}v=0\Leftarrow T^{i}v=0$) and if we suppose that $\ker T^{i}=\ker T^{i+1}$  for some $i$ than $\forall v \in v\in\ker T^{i+1}\ \ \ T^{i}v=T^{i+1}v=0$ and so if we take $u\in\ker T^{i+2}$ than 
$$
T^{i+2}u=0\Rightarrow TT^{i+1}u=0\Rightarrow TT^{i}u=0\Rightarrow T^{i+1}u=0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\ker T^{i+2}\subseteq\ker T^{i+1}\Rightarrow \ker T^{i+2}=\ker T^{i+1}
$$
and thus $\ker T^{n-2}=\ker T^{n-1}$ in contradiction.

So for every time we apply $T$ $\ker T^i$ has to be at least bigger by one from $\ker T^{i-1}$ for every $2\leq i \leq n-1$

Now I looked at the following cases:

a. if $\dim\ker T=0$ then the transformation is isomorphism and $\ker T^{n-2}=\ker T^{n-1} $ in contradiction.

b. if $\dim\ker T=2$ then $\dim \ker T^{n-1}=n$ and $T$ is Nilpotent and thus has only one eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ and the claim is correct.

c. if $\dim\ker T\geq3$ than again $\ker T^{n-2}=\ker T^{n-1} $ in contradiction.

d. this is the tricky part  : if $\dim\ker T=1$ then $\dim \ker T^{n-1}=n-1$ and i got stuck.

One thing that bothers me is that i didn't use the fact that $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed field. I think i ought to use it in d. but I'm not sure how.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: I would suggest tackling it from the other side. Suppose $T$ has at least $3$ distinct eigenvalues. Show that $\ker T^{n-1} = \ker T^{n-2}$. (The first part of what you have can still be used to great fruition.)

Comment: I did think about that but it didn't really get me any results. could be that I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe you missed that at least two of the three distinct eigenvalues are nonzero. (Just hinting, in the hope you'll find the trick yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

By your ascending chain, $\dim\ker T^k\ge k$ at least for $0\le k\le n-1$. Let $W=\ker T^{n-1}$. 
If $T$ is nilpotent then $0$ is th eonly eigenvalue. Therefore assume $T$ is not nilpotent.
We conclude $\dim W=n-1$. Also $\dim\ker T^n=n-1$, i.e. $W$ is $T$-invariant. Then all nonzero eigenvalues of $T$ are also eigenvalues of the induced endomorphism on $V/W$, but that space is $1$-dimensional.